# Why is current density a vector quantity while current is scalar?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

Electric current is considered to be a scalar quantity because it does not follow the rules of vector addition. Then, why is current density called a vector quantity as it is just current/area ?

Comment: Because the area has an orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, current (in a wire) is a vector.  However, because of a historical convention, it is denoted as a scalar.  In the case of a wire the direction is implicit as it is the local direction of the wire.  No such implicit assumption can be made for 2D or 3D current distributions.

A good way to appreciate the difference in how the vectorial nature is denoted is at the level of Biot-Savart law, where one has, for the infinitesimal source element
\begin{align}
Id\vec \ell &\qquad \hbox{for linear currents}\\
\vec J dV &\qquad \hbox{for (volume) currents}
\end{align}
with $\vec J$ the current density.  Both $Id\vec\ell$ and $\vec J dV$ are vectors.
In the first $Id\vec \ell$, the direction is captured in the vectorial element $d\vec \ell$ whereas in the second, the direction is captured in the vectorial density $\vec J$.